# publickey-authentication on git/stash for ssh not working

Tags: git, ssh, public-key, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to work with git/stash but I'm having a bit of a problem with the publickey-authentication. Here's what happens:

`hannibal` is a user on the stash-server. `hannibal` has read/write-permission for one repository and an ssh-publickey added to his stash-account. I now create a repository via

```
git init
```

and `add` & `commit` a test file `test`.
Then I want to add the stash-repository as origin

```
git remote add origin hannibal@stash:7999/path/to/repository.git
```

which yields no further output. Now I try to `push`

```
git push origin master
```

which in turn asks me for the password (which is strange, since it should authenticate via publickey). I enter the password and the following error message displays on the screen:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/hannibal: No such file or directory
fatal: '7999/path/to/repository.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The URL is definitely correct, since it's the one that stash gives me. Also ssh is enabled on the stash-server. What am I missing here?

Comment: From the above error "could not chdir to home directory", it appears a permission issue.  Pl check the permissions

Comment: What permissions should I check, considering that I only have access to the stash-web-frontend. The Permissions for the project and the repository are correct (read/write for `hannibal`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL for ssh remotes should be prefixed with ssh:// and the username should be git (Stash will find the correct key for your hannibal user automatically). The full form of the URL is:

```
ssh://git@server:7999/project/repo.git
```

For http URLs, you use the username and the http port (7990 by default)

Comment: Hmm, it really was the protocol. Okay, at least it's solved now...In fact, you can omit the user btw.